# Adding new user to PushMobi

Tags: appmobi, pushmobi

On an new device, but with an existing PushMobi user, do I need to call checkPushUser or addPushUser to add the user to the device?  Is it possible to use the webservice API to send a push message to an app hosted within the emulator, or from app lab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add an existing user to a new device you will need to call `AppMobi.notification.checkPushUser`

Comment: Where should i call this method?

Comment: @Hayzum to be honest I cant remember.  I ditched PushMobi a long time ago.